# VBA Excel - How can I automatically fill a series in excel, based on the value of another cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I have two columns in excel spreadsheet. 'Distance' and 'Bearing'. As shown in the below image the first distance value is *58.23* and the bearing value for the first distance is *-43.45* as shown in image 1.

[image: Image 1]

I want to divide the distance into a meter each, as in 1,2,3,4...58 (so that 58 meters is broken into 58 equal parts) in one column (Distance1) and fill the next column with value -43.45 (Bearing1) from 1 to 58 as shown in image 2. I want to generate this in a new sheet.

[image: Image 2]

After the first row, the code should go to the next distance row (i.e, 20.70) and repeat step 1, but should add it to the previous 1 to 58 cells. i.e 58, 59, 60 and fill the bearing1 column value with *-42.48* and so on. As shown in Image 3.

[image: Image 3]

I am new to VBA and will be really helpful if someone can help me out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of row counters and Single type variables and a few Loops will do.

As you are new to VBA, will not consider performance optimization here. Hope below untested code will get you love doing VBA programming. Code should self-explain the purpose. Ask if don't understand.

Here assuming Data is on columns A and B as per screenshot. And the output data will be from D2 and E2 downwards.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FillDistanceBearing()
    Dim lRowOutput As Long ' Row to start storing data
    Dim lDistance As Long ' Incremental Distance
    Dim lLoop1 As Long, lLoop2 As Long ' Row counters for Loops
    Dim gDistance As Single, gBearing As Single ' Variables to store the points

    lRowOutput = 2 ' Row to start storing the series at some column
    lDistance = 0 ' Start from zero

    ' #1 - Loop the main data
    lLoop1 = 2 ' For A2
    Do Until IsEmpty(Range(lLoop1, "A"))
        ' Store the Distance|Bearing values into variables
        gDistance = Range(lLoop1, "A").Value
        gBearing = Range(lLoop1, "B").Value
        ' #2 - Loop the distance from 1 to the integer value of the distance
        For lLoop2 = 1 To Int(gDistance)
            lDistance = lDistance + 1 ' Increment distance
            ' Store the values in Columns D and E for Distance1, Bearing1
            Range(lRowOutput, "D").Value = lDistance
            Range(lRowOutput, "E").Value = gBearing
            lRowOutput = lRowOutput + 1 ' Move to next row for storing output
        Next
        lLoop1 = lLoop1 + 1 ' Move to next data row
    Loop

End Sub
```